# SAP hana empty CLOB

Tags: hana, lob

How can I fetch all the rows from a table, where the CLOB content is empty (but not null)?
Table crate statement:

```
create column table "MY_SCHEM"."ISA_TMP"( "tenant_alias" varchar(500),"local_data" CLOB null);
```

I tried:

```
select * from "MY_SCHEM"."ISA_TMP"
where local_data = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check that by using the length() function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ISA_TMP
WHERE length(local_data) = 0;
```